# How to combine two list that contain intervals

Tags: python, linux, awk

I have list 1 and 2 and I would like to get list 3. If anyone can suggest python or awk script, that would be great.

```
List 1
A   100-160
B   200-500
C   800-1500
D   1600-2000
E   2500-3000

List 2
150
600
900
1700
2400


List 3
A   100-160        150
B   200-500 
C   800-1500    900
D   1600-2000   1700
E   2500-3000
```

Comment: does it adds from list 2 only if list2's value is between list1's values?

Comment: Please be explicit about what your logic is for both merging and sorting the result. I have removed the `ruby` tag from this question, as you did not ask for a solution using Ruby. If you are amenable to that, please edit your question to say so.

Comment: Do you need a Ruby script, and forgot to add that into the question, or did you accidentally add the ruby tag?

Comment: Are you saying you have some text that contains those lists (say, in a file) and you want text that contains list 3, possibly in another file? I'm unclear what "data types" we're talking about since you're agnostic about the programming language.

Comment: The list one contains intervals and the list 2 contains some values (not all) that fall within the intervals of the first list. If they do (values of the second list), I want to match them with first one. There could be more than one value in the second list that fall in one interval of the first one.

Comment: List one and two are in two different files and I would like to create the third file with list 3. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example.  It is expecting two filenames to be passed on the command line.

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print 'parameters: list1 list2'
    sys.exit(1)

list1 = []
for line in file(sys.argv[1]):
    fields = line.split()
    f1 = fields[0]
    f2, f3 = fields[1].split('-')
    list1.append((f1, int(f2), int(f3), [], ))

for line in file(sys.argv[2]):
    value = int(line)
    for name, lb, ub, values in list1:
        if value >= lb and value <= ub:
            values.append(str(value))

for name, lb, ub, values in list1:
    if values: vals = ','.join(values)
    else: vals = ''
    print '%s %d-%d %s' % (name, lb, ub, vals, )
```

Comment: Thanks FuzzyWuzzy. This worked well, except that I had to changed the original names Solyc08g007690.1.1 to 1, 2, 3..

Answer (score 2):

You could make a dictionary from list 1 that contains the intervals then loops through it to see if any value in list 2 is inside the range. For example,

```
list1 = {"A": [100, 160], "B": [200, 500], "C": [800, 1500],
         "D": [1600, 2000], "E": [2500,3000]}

list2 = [150, 600, 900, 1700, 2400]

for key, val in list1.iteritems():
    for num in list2:
        if num in range(val[0], val[1]):
            val.append(num)

for key, val in sorted(list1.iteritems()):
    print key, ":", val
```

Comment: One issue with that is he will lose the ordering from List 1 (python will randomize the orders of the keys). It comes out "A, C, B, E, D" when I run it.

Comment: It would be better to use `xrange()` over `range()` in case the the range is rather large.

Comment: Well, the xrange thing is really just for really large numbers, where memory is an issue. Like trying to calculate all the primes under 1billion. Xrange would be good for that. For something like this, range is really fine. To fix the issue with non sorting, I'll just have to change something real quick to sort the keys when the dictionary is looped through to print off.

Comment: actually, for this you shouldn't use range or xrange, just do `if val[0]<=num<val[1]`

Comment: I threw this together in 2 minutes people! It's not optimized :O.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this in Python:

```
L1 = [(100, 160), (200, 500), (800, 1500), (1600, 2000), (2500, 3000)]
L2 = [150, 600, 900, 1700, 2400]
L3 = [((a, b), [i for i in L2 if a<=i<b]) for (a, b) in L1]
```

It's easy to parse the data into that structure if that's what you want (and print it back out), but I'll wait until you explain what format the data comes in and what format you need it in, because I have a feeling there will be a catch to it.

Comment: List one and two are in two different files and I would like to create the third file with list 3. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Well, @FuzzyWuzzy did pretty much what I was going to do in the meantime, so nm about changing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do it simply on the command line.So far this is the only awk solution among all:

```
 paste list1 list2|awk '{split($2,a,"-");
                           if($3>a[1] && $3<a[2])
                           {h=$3}
                           else
                           {h=""};
                           print $1,$2,h}'

A 100-160 150
B 200-500
C 800-1500 900
D 1600-2000 1700
E 2500-3000
```

Answer (score 0):

Dunno for sure if Ruby is needed, but here's a quick pass at it:

```
list1 = %w[ A 100-160 B 200-500 C 800-1500 D 1600-2000 E 2500-3000 ]
list2 = %w[ 150, 600, 900, 1700, 2400 ]

list3 = []

list1.each_slice(2) do |char, range|
  min_range, max_range = range.split('-').map{ |i| i.to_i }
  l2 = list2.shift
  case l2.to_i
  when min_range..max_range
    list3 << [ char, range, l2 ]
  else
    list3 << [ char, range ]
  end
end

require 'pp'
pp list3

>> [["A", "100-160", "150,"],
>>  ["B", "200-500"],
>>  ["C", "800-1500", "900,"],
>>  ["D", "1600-2000", "1700,"],
>>  ["E", "2500-3000"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take.  I just made up the parsing and printing bit since you didn't specify.

```
list_1 = ['A\t100-160', 'B\t200-500', 'C\t800-1500', 'D\t1600-2000', 'E\t2500-3000']
list_2 = [150, 600, 900, 1700, 2400]

for range in list_1:
    # parse the input (this may be different, but you didn't specify)
    lower_bound, upper_bound = range.split('\t')[1].split('-')  # this is a bit fragile
    lower_bound = int(lower_bound)
    upper_bound = int(upper_bound)

    # make sure lower_bound is less than upper_bound
    if upper_bound < lower_bound:
        (lower_bound, upper_bound) = (upper_bound, lower_bound)

    # loop over list 2 and see if any fall into the current range
    items_in_range = [str(number) for number in list_2 if lower_bound <= number < upper_bound]

    # output List 3
    print range + '\t' + ','.join(items_in_range)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use iterable tools to write this. Not all too readable but this works. Definitely was fun to write!

```
from itertools import chain

nameranges = ['A', '100-160', 'B', '200-500', 'C', '800-1500', 'D', '1600-2000', 
              'E', '2500-3000']

values = [150, 600, 900, 1700, 2400]
z = zip(nameranges[0::2], ( map(int, x.split("-")) for x in nameranges[1::2]))
f = list(chain(* (map(lambda x, y: (x[0][0], x[1][0], x[1][1], y) 
               if x[1][0]<=y<=x[1][1] else (x[0], x[1][0], x[1][1]), 
               z, values))))
# print f
#['A', 100, 160, 150, 'B', 200, 500, 'C', 800, 1500, 900, 'D', 1600, 2000, 1700, 
# 'E', 2500, 3000]
```